# c++ template<typename T> delete

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I am playing around with my containers.

In my template class for an container i make a pointer of `T*` (`T* mData;`) as a member variable of the container class. This is a pointer to an array type.

In the destructor i call the `delete` keyword `delete mData;` or `delete[] mData;` but all i hear is a ding in the test application and no more output is write to the console.

Can someone please explain what is going on is deleting a member of `T* mData;` somehow different to deleting everything else? if so can someone please explain I've looked everywhere and can't find an answer.

**UPDATE**

I read the comments and since people were willing to help in return i have decided to post the this update and answer the question itself. Ps don't laugh it was a silly mistake.

OLD CODE (looked something like this)

```
template<typename T>
class TestVector {
// members
T* mData;
size_t mSize;

// methods
void AddData(T data){
    T* buffer;
    memcpy_s(buffer, sizeof(mData), mData, sizeof(mData));

    if(!buffer){
        // log error
        return;
    }

    mSize++;
    SafeDelete(mData);            // deleting this here was the problem (check destructor)
    mData = new T[mSize];

    mData = buffer;
    mData[mSize - 1] = data;
}

// constructors
TestVector(void){
    mData = new T[0];
    ZeroMemory(mData, sizeof(mData);
    mSize = 0;
}
~TestVector(void){
    SafeDelete(mData);           // when deleting the mData member again here the problem would occur, the destructor was called the beep noise would sound and the console window would freeze
}

// operators
};
```

I will answer what i did to change this as a Answer to the question . . .

Comment: Present your [MCVE].

Comment: *"all i hear is a ding in the test application"* - this is a new one.  Have you written a custom allocator which makes sounds?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Undefined behaviour has many disguises. In reality this is likely a response from the surrounding environment to a program crash. Obviously without actually being able to _see_ said program we cannot diagnose it. Don't understand why MCVEs are so rarely provided up-front.

Comment: Thank you i am using [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Apparently initialising it in the default constructor allows for it to be deleted without this for an unknown reason the code will compile but at run time the program undefined behaviour. It also gives no help i just messed about just in case anyone reads in to this.

Comment: @AliceFluff where is the code?

Comment: I solved it, it was me just being dumb. I choose to use `malloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()`instead of new and delete. I was simply making a `class Vector { // classy stuff here };` i need to reallocate and deallocate as the size increased and decreased. However custom implementations might be faster for reliability and speed of development i have decided to use the STL

Comment: Ill put an answer to the question anyway in case others run into this problem

Comment: Your example isn't nearly complete enough for anyone to do anything other than guess at the issue, but a common problem with raw pointers is not following the rule of three. The object is somehow copied, both raw pointers point to the same place, and you have a double delete when they are destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I will admit i do not understand why deleting the same pointer of the class more than once gave an error, maybe the memory address of the new pointer wasn't know to the class so the destructor couldn't find it but to solve the issue i went with old school C.

```
template<typename T>
class TestVector {
private:
    T * mData;
    size_t mSize = 0;

public:
    TestVector(void) {
        mSize = 2;
        mData = (T*)malloc(mSize * sizeof(T));

        for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++) {
            mData[i] = i;
        }

        cout << "Values in t1 are: " << mData[0] << ", " << mData[1] << endl;
    }
    ~TestVector(void) {
        free(mData);        // only place the pointer is ever deleted
    }

public:
    void AddData(T data) {
        mSize++;
        T* newData = (T*)realloc(mData, mSize * sizeof(T));
        mData = newData;

        mData[mSize - 1] = data;

        for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++) {
            cout << "Value: " << i << " is equal to: " << mData[i] << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

I just used `malloc()` to allocate, `realloc()` to reallocate a bigger array to the pointer and `free()` to release the pointer.

I could of just omitted the `SafeDelete(mData);` in the first version and just called `new` over the top i think but i actually prefer using old school C for this type of thing, it makes more sense :)

Comment: ps this is my first attempt at writing my own vector

Comment: Assuming you're still not following the rule of three this code still has the potential for a double free, and as undefined behavior goes it may seem to work great until it doesn't.

Comment: Please explain how so i can look into making the code more robust

Comment: If you supplied an actual complete example showing the full class and how you are using it that is causing a crash that would be possible. Right now it is not worth guessing about. You can read about the rule of three yourself.

Comment: I understand what the rule of three is, i can handle that. However the main problem with the above code was solved. The class wouldn't need to be completed to avoid the issues that could arise

Comment: Has the problem been fixed or do you now have a new problem that you haven't found yet. In your question in AddData you declare an uninitialized pointer and then use memcpy to copy to it. Then you allocate space using mData and immediately overwrite mData with buffer. You've caused a memory leak and have a pointer that points to nowhere you'll delete later and maybe crash or maybe not. At the very least you've corrupted the heap. That's the first mess. In the constructor you allocate enough memory for 0 items, then you ZeroMemory an item you have not allocated space for using the wrong size.

Comment: The code you have in this answer is somewhat better, but what's going to happen when you add something to it that has a constructor?

Comment: The actual code i don't have anymore. This is from my memory lol. I was writing it night but decided to scrap it in favour using the STL as it's reliable and works right out the box, i was just attempting to make some very lightweight and quick containers. I understand they maybe memory leaks as the code above was only typed in here and never test it just roughly what i remember because people were asking in the comments for more code i felt it polite to oblige since the offered help. So i merely wrote what i remember :)